# Entity framework model data doesn't appears when I want to add new model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've made a project with Asp.net core, and i have some data in slq express. I want to add entity framework whit my existing database, but at the moment to add the model doesn't appears the model data, I tried installing NutGet packages and update them, but nothing.

[Thats all that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChbJt.png)

Comment: Please post code, not simply a link.  Show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: What do you mean `add the model doesn't appears the model data`?If you want to create a model class manually, then create a Class, if you would like to create model from existing database,then use db-first as the answer has shown.

Comment: check this article on how to use entity framework core for an exsisting db: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to add ado.net entity model. You can try to generate using the follwoing for .net core

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db